# Skip observable on retry

Tags: java, rx-java

I am concating RX observables using concat operator. I am also using retry operator to retry in case of any error. However, I would like to skip some observable from source on retry. Is it possible ?

```java
Observable.concat (
    Observable-A,
    Observable-B,
    Observable-C
).retry(ERROR);
```

So for example, if Observable-A completes but Observable-B produces error, then on retry I only want to re-subscribe Observable-B and Observable-C.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply retry to each `Observable` so that the retry affects each of them independently from the other ones:

```
Observable.concat (
    Observable-A.retry(ERROR),
    Observable-B.retry(ERROR),
    Observable-C.retry(ERROR)
)
```